# Can't resolve all parameters -getting this error in browser angular2

Tags: angular2-services

I am trying to create a movie finder website using api key .Everything looks perfect as far as code as well as the api key -i could access the values  just by hitting the api request but getting error in browser.Appreciate if some one can help me

Error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xkec.png)

This is My  movies.service.ts

```
 import {Injectable} from  '@angular/core';
import {Jsonp,JsonpModule} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

Injectable()

export class MovieService
{
apikey:string;
constructor(private _jsonp:Jsonp)
    {
this.apikey='##';
console.log('Movie Service Initialized');
    }

getPopular()
{

return this._jsonp.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=##')
.map(res=>res.json());
}

}
```

This is my movies.components.ts where i am calling the service

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from 'app/services/movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'Movies',
  templateUrl: 'movies.components.html',

})
export class MoviesComponent {

    constructor(private _movieservice:MovieService)
    {
           this._movieservice.getPopular().subscribe(res=>{

               console.log(res.results)
           });

    }

}
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule,JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MoviesComponent} from 'app/components/movies/movies.components';
import {MovieService} from  'app/services/movies.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MoviesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,

  ],
  providers: [MovieService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've probably solved this already. The only thing I see is that you're missing an '@' symbol before your Injectable in the MovieService. Hope that helps!